# Why am I getting "setterm: $TERM is not defined" when I SSH into another server?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, remote-server, mobaxterm

I'm SSH-ing from one remote server to another to run a couple of commands. My here-doc runs fine on the destination server but I'm getting this `setterm: $TERM is not defined` warning even though it is defined as linux on both servers. I tried `export TERM=linux` before the ssh command and in the Here-Doc.

Here-doc:

```
ssh -T $DestinationServer <<EOF
     export TERM=linux
     echo "Successfully SSH into \$HOSTNAME..."
     echo \$TERM
     *do some stuff*
EOF
```

Output:

```
setterm: $TERM is not defined.
Successfully SSH into HOSTNAME..."
linux
```

How do I fix this? And does this effect other commands in the Here-Doc?

**UPDATE**
I scrapped the Here-Doc and the setterm error went away. While it fixed my problem, why did the error resolve when I do it this way?

```
DoesThisExist=$(ssh -T $DestServer "cat $SomeFile" | grep -cim1 $This")
```

Comment: You may be interested in this reply: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/528323/what-uses-the-term-variable

Comment: In your `EOF` block, add an `export TERM=???` as the first line.  ??? can be many values, but try the basic `xterm` or `linux` to start.

Comment: @Nic3500 Sorry, I failed to mention I tried `export TERM=linux` in the EOF and before the EOF block. Also, I scrapped the whole here-doc since I needed to pass just one command via SSH.

Comment: These changes should be reflected in your question.  Edit it.

Comment: @SimonDoppler Thank you for the article. From what I understand from it, the ssh command opens a Bash shell in the remote server that uses Terminfo. Is that right?